# Swift Vapor "add" button is showing error

Tags: swift, vapor, leaf

When I click on add button it shows error: `{error: true,
reason: "Not Found"}

`configure.swift` code:

```swift
import FluentSQLite
import Vapor
import Leaf // added
public func configure(_ config: inout Config, _ env: inout Environment, _ services: inout Services) throws {
    // Register providers first
    try services.register(FluentSQLiteProvider())
    
    // Register routes to the router
    let router = EngineRouter.default()
    try routes(router)
    services.register(router, as: Router.self)
    
    // Register middleware
    var middlewares = MiddlewareConfig() // Create _empty_ middleware config
    // middlewares.use(FileMiddleware.self) // Serves files from `Public/` directory
    middlewares.use(ErrorMiddleware.self) // Catches errors and converts to HTTP response
    services.register(middlewares)
    
    let directoryConfig = DirectoryConfig.detect()
    services.register(directoryConfig)
    let sqlite = try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .file(path:"\(directoryConfig.workDir)pizza.db"))
    var databases = DatabasesConfig()
    databases.add(database: sqlite, as: .sqlite)
    services.register(databases)
    
    var migrations = MigrationConfig()
    migrations.add(model: Todo.self, database: .sqlite)
    migrations.add(model: Pizza.self, database: .sqlite)
    services.register(migrations)
    
    let leafProvider = LeafProvider()    // added
    try services.register(leafProvider)  // added
    config.prefer(LeafRenderer.self, for: ViewRenderer.self)// added
    let serverConfigure = NIOServerConfig.default(hostname: "0.0.0.0", port: 9090)
    services.register(serverConfigure)
}
```

`pizza.swift` code:

```
import Foundation
import Vapor
import FluentSQLite

struct Pizza: SQLiteModel, Content, SQLiteMigration, Migration {
    var id:  Int?
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var  price: Int
}
```

`routes.swift` code:

```
import Routing
import Vapor
import FluentSQLite
public func routes(_ router: Router) throws {
    router.get { req -> Future <View> in
        let Newyorker = Pizza(id: 5, name: "statinisland", description: "impracticaljokers", price: 55)
        let Traditional = Pizza(id: 5, name: "rome", description: "pope", price: 55)
        return try req.view().render("welcome",["pizza":[Newyorker,Traditional]])
    }
    router.post(Pizza.self, at: "add") { req, pizza in
        return pizza
    }
}
```

`welcome.leaf screenshot:

[image]

`localhost` screenshot:

[image]

`error` screenshot:

[image]

Unable to figure out. Thanks.

Edit 1.  I have pasted the leaf file -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
  <h1> Pizza </h1>
  <p> Welcome to best pizza in the  world  </p>
 <ul>
   #for(pizza in pizza)  {
  <li>(pizza.name)</li>
  }
  </ul>
 </body>
 </html>

 <form method="post" action="/add">
 <p>Name: <input type="text" name = "name" /></p>
 <p>Descrition: <input type="text" name = "description" /></p>
 <p>Price: <input type="number" name = "price" /></p>
 <button type="submit">Add</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: It would be easier if you included your `.leaf` file as text rather than an image.

Comment: @Nick  - i)somehow stackoverflow does not acccept the leaf file as it is, but posting leaf file as well. So, I posted screenshot. ii)So, how to get result from form ?

Comment: has anyone started the bounty ? I have not done it ?

Comment: When I post your .leaf file in, it finds the route and works perfectly. It isn't possible you've got an old, cached version in your browser, is it?

Comment: maybe, becuse, when  I delete these lines - "let serverConfigure = NIOServerConfig.default(hostname: "0.0.0.0", port: 9090)
    services.register(serverConfigure)", in configure.swift, it still opens localhost:9090, whats the cure ?

Comment: Are you using Xcode? It's sometimes possible to have an old instance running in the background.

Comment: yes, using xcode. I clean-built folder, cleared derived data, restarted xcode, still no avail.

Comment: @Nick - had to restart the computer, which cleared cache.

Comment: Now, a new problem succeeds but firefox cannot connect to localhost - message  "Unable to connect"

"Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:9090".i) I tried with localhost:8080 ii) I tried a different browser as well, all in vain. If  anyone could ssuggest anything, would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I mean xcode build succeeds but cannot connect to localhost.

Comment: @Oops my bad, I had, it should be "run" in the scheme menu. Localhost problem has been solved, but a new problem has arisen for which I am posting a new question.